# Any difference between Component.CompareTag() and GameObject.CompreTag()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to know if there's any under-the-hood difference in the execution of these two CompareTag() calls:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherCollider)
{
    if (otherCollider.CompareTag("TestTag"))
    {
        Debug.Log("The other Collider is tagged: TestTag");
    }

    if (otherCollider.gameObject.CompareTag("TestTag"))
    {
        Debug.Log("The other GameObject is tagged: TestTag");
    }
}
```

I suspect they should be identical – a Component is always attached to one and only one GameObject, so it
shouldn't be necessary to access the Component's ".gameObject" reference first.  Both calls behave identically as far as I can tell.

I wonder because:

1. Calling otherCollider.gameObject.CompareTag() doesn't result in a “name can be simplified” warning.  This could be because those classes and methods are in the UnityEngine namespace, and thus not covered by VisualStudio's warnings?
2. The example in the Unity documentation for Component.CompareTag() explicitly uses the longer form of the call: other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player").  This could just be the result of a sloppy copy-paste from the GameObject.CompareTag() method's documentation, which provides an identical example?
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html

Comment: Most of these redundant calls (`CompareTag`, `GetComponent`, etc) are just shortcuts doing exactly the same thing ... So no! ... To 2) .. the examples in the API unfortunately are often nonsense :D

Comment: @ derHugo Well, they are doing parallel things, but according to the answer below, they are not exactly the same.  And more importantly, my intuition was wrong, and the apparently longer callpath actually has marginally smaller overhead.

Comment: Well yes .. but honestly this is minimal really .. unless you do that like 10.000 times per frame it won't matter at all. You will find these kind of shortcuts/forwardings in a lot of APIs since it is really just a call more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the actual code for `Component.CompareTag()`, you'll see this:

```cs
    // UnityEngine.Component
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Is this game object tagged with tag ?</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag">The tag to compare.</param>
    public bool CompareTag(string tag)
    {
        return gameObject.CompareTag(tag);
    }
```

So, if you want to get down to the "under the hood" implementation, at a micro-optimisation level, when you call `Component.CompareTag()`, you're ALSO calling the `gameObject` property as well, which has it's own processing time associated with accessing it. Now, that processing time isn't huge, but it IS there because properties have similar processing overheads to method calls, as they're *essentially* the same.

The process then goes Component.CompareTag() -> Component.gameObject{get} -> GameObject.CompareTag().

So, the long and short of it is, that if you can call a method further down the call stack, instead of a top level helper method, you're best to chose the more performant one - `GameObject.CompareTag()`.

As for the example you gave, it's essentially saving one method call, by accessing the Component `gameObject` property directly.